# Remove [Windows-10] synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Currently, the [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) tag is mapped as a synonym to Windows-10-preview.  However, as of tomorrow it will no longer be the preview, it will be the final version.  So the synonym should be removed and let it stand on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done the following:

- Removed tag synonym for [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) > [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview)
- Merged [windows-10-final](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-final) into [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) and created synonym